# How to get data nested with nested fields in redux-form?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-form

I have a scenario where there is a list of items and each items have name and value selector side by side(so two inputs). The user selects the name (its radio button) and then selects the value. I am using `redux-form` and so far what I achieved:

`<Field name='item1' component={DropDownPicker} />
<Field name='item2' component={DropDownPicker} />`

submitting gives value as `{item1: 1, item2: 2}`

Now there will lots of values for different category items and the it will be a big messy object with all category data in one place and I want to avoid that.

How can I get this one item data as `{first: {item1: 1, item2: 2}}` or as a collection `[{item1: 1, item2: 2}]`

Comment: Did you try to store the data as a list of objects?

Comment: that might not help me in this case because the input might change

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wrap items into `first` object:

```
<Field name='first.item1' component={DropDownPicker} />
<Field name='first.item2' component={DropDownPicker} />
```

On submitting you'll get `{first: {item1: 1, item2: 2}}`.

Comment: generic Field validation does not work in this case
```const required = value => value ? undefined : 'Required';```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `FormSection`

```
import { FormSection } from 'redux-form';
```

then..

```
<FormSection name="first">
  <Field name="item1" component={DropDownPicker} />
  <Field name="item2" component={DropDownPicker} />
<FormSection>
```